# How to convert "["1","2"]" to ["1","2"] in dart?

Tags: flutter, dart

```
metas: "["<p>1</p>","<p>2</p>","<p>3/p>","<p>4</p>"]"
to 
List<String> metas = ["<p>1</p>","<p>2</p>","<p>3/p>","<p>4</p>"]
```

I can use it in JS JSON.parse (meta), is there any way to do it in dart?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use could use the `jsonDecode` function from `dart:convert`

```dart
import 'dart:convert';
void main() {
  
  var x = '["<p>1</p>","<p>2</p>","<p>3/p>","<p>4</p>"]';
  
  List metas = jsonDecode(x);
  
  print(metas); // [<p>1</p>, <p>2</p>, <p>3/p>, <p>4</p>]
  print(metas[0].runtimeType); // String 
}
```